# Informatica BDM - How to re-try "REST Web Service Consumer"?

Tags: rest, informatica, retry-logic

I have an **Informatica BDM system** (note Big Data Management, not Power Centre) and am having a problem with dropping connections when communicating with a third party web service. This fails the REST web service transformation which in turn kills our batch job.

Rather than fail the entire job, I would like each **REST call** to potentially be retried several times first.

I looked at the documentation, but I see no option to set a re-try on the **REST Web Service Consumer transformation.** Did I miss it? Or does one have to construct a re-try loop around it in some other way?

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using and the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad News, But the Informatica BDM is yet to come up with an option to Retry. The need for the feature is already been raised by many users and may be the option will come up in the upcoming releases.

For now, we can only keep track of all the requests and responses manually and hope for the best.

Comment: The product seems very immature - this is only 1 of tens of issues we have had with it...